# access restrictions for openssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

I would need some advice for those who want to help :

I have a linux server, and I want to provide an ssh (openssh) access to services like rsync, and sftp, for a specific user (extuser).

1) I'd like to restrict extuser to only process rsync or sftp, no other commands

2) extuser needs to read/write some specific directories, so I want to restrict what he can see and where he can write.

3) I'd read some about rbash or lshell, but i wanted to know if by "basic" configuration of openssh, without adding specific tools, i could manage it ?

Here is my reflexion (not very far, sorry)

- For the 1) If i had only rsync to deal with, i've seen the rrsync script that is really helpfull :) But how to add  the sftp restriction ? I've read about the "command=" in authorized_keygen and the use of variable SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND, but not sure if it is mainly dedicated for ssh command explicitely used (i.e ssh user@host "mycommand"), not for command that "internally" use ssh like rsync or sftp ?
- For the 2), I think the chroot option for sftp will help

If you have any advices, remarks, are if you see i'm going in wrong way, i'd apreciate some returns :)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it appears that the chroot can fullfill all the needs, since it's up to me to choose the commands i want to allow in the "chrooted" bin :)

So no commands restrictions by openssh configuration, but by chroot arborescence. And therefore i don't seem to need extra tools :)